# If $0 < r < 1$ show that $r^n$ goes to $0$ as $n \to ∞$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $0 < r < 1$ show that $r^n$ goes to $0$ as $n \to  ∞$.

If $|r| < 1$ then

$r^2  < r$

similarly $r^4 < r^3 < r^2 < r$

so $r^n$ as $n \to +\infty$ will be equal to $∞$

Let $r=\frac1m , m>1 \to$ you need to show $$lim_{n\to +\infty} r^n = ∞$$
Since $0<r<1$
$$lim_{n\to +\infty} r^n = lim_{n\to +\infty} \left(\frac1m\right)^n=lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{m^n} = \frac{1}{+\infty} = ∞$$

Comment: *"Let $r=\frac1{m},m \gt 1$ show that $$lim_{n\to +\infty} r^n = \infty$$"* that is so wrong.

Comment: If you have questions about the answers to your previous question, do not ask the same question again, leave a comment.

Comment: @Dilek. I showed you a simple proof in your previous post. My proof also works for this question, where you end up with $lny=-inf$ implying y→0. Have you read the answers?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use $\epsilon-N$ definition.

suppose given a $\epsilon$, then pick $N=\lceil\log_r{\epsilon}\rceil$, as we can see for every $n>N$, $|r^n-0|<\epsilon$, so $\lim_{n\to \infty}r^n=0$